# can we make a reactjs component of json data and use it in the project to fetch data by importing it

Tags: json, reactjs

I am using reactjs, nodejs to build a project and created a component Dummy.json in which i inserted the code below:

```
var Dummy={
    "items":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"manish"
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Ashok"
        }
    ]
}

export default Dummy;
```

Now i wanted to import this component in App.js like below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Dummy from './Dummy.json';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <p>{this.Dummy.items}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

How to do this as i am getting error

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/Dummy.json Syntax error: Unexpected token v in JSON at position
>   0
>       at JSON.parse ()

Answer (score 0):

Convert `{this.Dummy.items}` to `{Dummy.items}`.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, your `Dummy.json` is not a component. It's not at all clear what you're expecting to happen here.

With regards to the specific error you're getting, it's because `Dummy.json` is not a json file at all, it's a js file. A json file should solely be json formatted text. So instead you could do:

```
// Dummy.json
{
  "items":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "name":"manish"
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Ashok"
    }
  ]
}

// in App.js
import Dummy from './Dummy.json'
```

But unless there's a reason this file needs to be json, you should just treat it like the js file that it is. Rename it to `Dummy.js` and then import it like any other js file:

```
// in App.js
import Dummy from './Dummy'
```

In both cases you can then use (for example) `Dummy.items` to get the items array. Again though, that is **not** a component, and trying to render it the way you are (i.e. `<p>{Dummy.items}</p>`, no `this` needed), is probably going to throw an error ("Objects are not valid as a React child").